# shiny app excelR can't control table height

Tags: shiny, excelr

I'm using ExcelR and Shiny. I can't seem to make the table bigger than say, 13 rows.

Here is example code:

```
shinyApp(
    ui =  navbarPage("title", selected = "main", 
        position = "fixed-top", 
        tags$style(type="text/css", "body {padding-top: 70px;}"),
        tabPanel("main", id = "main",
            fluidPage(                
                excelOutput("table", width = "100%", height = "100%")
            )
        )
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
        output$table <-renderExcel(
            excelTable(
                data = iris,
                autoColTypes = FALSE,
                pagination = 5,
                #autoFill = TRUE,
                fullscreen = FALSE,
                lazyLoading = TRUE,
                search = TRUE  
            )
        )
    }
)
```

pagination seems to have no effect, and if I switch fullscreen on, the rest of the rows are rendered, but I can't see the searchbar, and the padding between the table and the navbar disappears.

I'm running R 3.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to leave this question open for a few days to see if anyone has a better answer.

For now, I managed to hack a solution by changing the excelTable function.

I added the line `paramList$tableHeight <- "500px"` to the function, and renamed the function excelTable2.

I found this param on the website for jExcel: [jExcel Parameters](https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v2/docs/quick-reference)

I guess I will probably add the height as an input parameter to excelTable2.

```
excelTable2 = function (data = NULL, columns = NULL, colHeaders = NULL, rowHeight = NULL, 
    nestedHeaders = NULL, defaultColWidth = NULL, minDimensions = NULL, 
    columnSorting = TRUE, columnDrag = FALSE, columnResize = TRUE, 
    rowResize = FALSE, rowDrag = TRUE, editable = TRUE, allowInsertRow = TRUE, 
    allowInsertColumn = TRUE, allowDeleteRow = TRUE, allowDeleteColumn = TRUE, 
    allowRenameColumn = TRUE, allowComments = FALSE, wordWrap = FALSE, 
    selectionCopy = TRUE, mergeCells = NULL, search = FALSE, 
    pagination = NULL, fullscreen = FALSE, lazyLoading = FALSE, 
    loadingSpin = FALSE, style = NULL, autoColTypes = TRUE, showToolbar = FALSE, 
    dateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY", digits = 4, autoWidth = TRUE, 
    autoFill = FALSE, getSelectedData = FALSE, ...) 
{
    paramList <- list()
    if (!is.null(data)) {
        if (is.data.frame(data) || is.matrix(data)) {
            paramList$data <- jsonlite::toJSON(data, dataframe = "values", 
                na = "null", digits = digits)
        }
        else {
            stop("'data' must be either a matrix or a data frame, cannot be ", 
                class(data))
        }
    }
    if (is.null(columns) && is.null(colHeaders)) {
        if (!is.null(data)) {
            warning("Since both column title and colHeaders are not specified 'data' column name will be used as column headers")
            paramList$colHeaders = colnames(data)
        }
    }
    else if (is.null(columns) && !is.null(colHeaders)) {
        if (!is.vector(colHeaders)) {
            stop("'colHeaders' must be a vector, cannot be ", 
                class(colHeaders))
        }
        if (!is.null(data)) {
            if (ncol(data) != length(colHeaders)) {
                stop("length of 'colHeader' should be equal the number of columns in the 'data', 'data' has ", 
                  ncol(data), "but the length of 'colHeader' is ", 
                  length(colHeaders))
            }
        }
        paramList$colHeaders <- jsonlite::toJSON(colHeaders)
    }
    else if (!is.null(columns)) {
        if (!is.data.frame(columns)) {
            stop("'columns' must be a dataframe, cannot be ", 
                class(columns))
        }
        if (!is.null(data)) {
            if (nrow(columns) != ncol(data)) {
                stop("number of rows in 'columns' should be equal to number of columns in 'data', expected number of rows in 'columns' to be ", 
                  ncol(data), " but got ", nrow(columns))
            }
        }
        if (!"title" %in% colnames(columns)) {
            if (is.null(colHeaders)) {
                if (!is.null(data)) {
                  warning("Since both column title and colHeaders are not specified 'data' column name will be used as column headers")
                  paramList$colHeaders = jsonlite::toJSON(colnames(data))
                }
            }
            else {
                paramList$colHeaders = jsonlite::toJSON(colHeaders)
            }
        }
        paramList$columns <- jsonlite::toJSON(columns)
    }
    if (autoColTypes && !is.null(data)) {
        if (is.null(columns)) {
            message("Since 'type' attribute is not specified and autoColTypes is true, detecting type from 'data'")
            colTypes <- get_col_types(data)
            columns <- data.frame(type = colTypes)
            columns <- add_source_for_dropdown_type(data, columns)
            paramList$columns <- jsonlite::toJSON(columns)
        }
        else {
            if (!"type" %in% colnames(columns) && autoColTypes) {
                message("Since 'type' attribute is not specified and autoColTypes is true, detecting type from 'data'")
                colTypes <- get_col_types(data)
                columns$type <- colTypes
                columns <- add_source_for_dropdown_type(data, 
                  columns)
                paramList$columns <- jsonlite::toJSON(columns)
            }
        }
    }
    if (!is.null(rowHeight)) {
        if (!is.data.frame(rowHeight) && !is.matrix(rowHeight)) {
            stop("'rowHeight' must either be a matrix or a dataframe, cannot be ", 
                class(rowHeight))
        }
        if (ncol(rowHeight) != 2) {
            stop("'rowHeight' must either be a matrix or a dataframe with two columns, but got ", 
                ncol(rowHeight), " column(s)")
        }
        paramList$rowHeight <- jsonlite::toJSON(rowHeight, dataframe = "values")
    }
    if (!is.null(nestedHeaders)) {
        if (!is.list(nestedHeaders)) {
            stop("'nestedHeaders' must be a list of dataframe(s), cannot be ", 
                class(nestedHeaders))
        }
        headerAttributes <- c("title", "colspan")
        for (nestedHeader in nestedHeaders) {
            if (!is.data.frame(nestedHeader)) {
                stop("'nestedHeaders' must be a list of dataframe(s), but got list of  ", 
                  class(nestedHeader), "(s)")
            }
            if (ncol(nestedHeader) < 2 || nrow(nestedHeader) < 
                1) {
                stop("the dataframe(s) in 'nestedHeaders must contain at least two columns and one row, 'title' and 'colspan', but got only ", 
                  ncol(nestedHeader), " column and ", nrow(nestedHeader), 
                  " row")
            }
            if (!"title" %in% colnames(nestedHeader)) {
                stop("one of the column in the dataframe in list of 'nestedHeaders' should have 'title' as header which will be used as title of the nested header")
            }
            if (!"colspan" %in% colnames(nestedHeader)) {
                stop("one of the column in the dataframe in list of 'nestedHeaders' should have 'colspan' as header which will be used to determine the number of column it needs to span")
            }
            if (!all(colnames(nestedHeader) %in% headerAttributes)) {
                warning("unknown headers(s) ", colnames(nestedHeader)[!colnames(nestedHeader) %in% 
                  headerAttributes], " for 'nestedHeader' found, ignoring column with those header(s)")
            }
        }
        paramList$nestedHeaders <- jsonlite::toJSON(nestedHeaders, 
            dataframe = "rows")
    }
    if (!is.null(defaultColWidth)) {
        if (!is.numeric(defaultColWidth) || length(defaultColWidth) > 
            1) {
            stop("'defaultColWidth' must be a numeric value of length 1 but got ", 
                class(defaultColWidth), " of length ", 
                length(defaultColWidth))
        }
        paramList$defaultColWidth <- defaultColWidth
    }
    if (!is.null(minDimensions)) {
        if (!is.vector(minDimensions)) {
            stop("'minDimensions' must be vector but got ", 
                class(minDimensions))
        }
        if (length(minDimensions) != 2) {
            stop("'minDimensions' must be a vector of length of 2 but got length of ", 
                length(minDimensions))
        }
        paramList$minDimensions <- minDimensions
    }
    for (arg in c("columnSorting", "columnDrag", 
        "columnResize", "rowResize", "rowDrag", 
        "editable", "allowInsertRow", "allowInsertColumn", 
        "allowDeleteRow", "allowDeleteColumn", "allowRenameColumn", 
        "allowComments", "wordWrap", "selectionCopy", 
        "search", "fullscreen", "lazyLoading", 
        "loadingSpin", "showToolbar", "autoWidth", 
        "autoFill", "getSelectedData")) {
        argvalue <- get(arg)
        if (!is.null(argvalue)) {
            if (is.logical(argvalue)) {
                paramList[[arg]] <- argvalue
            }
            else {
                warning("Argument ", arg, " should be either TRUE or FALSE.  Ignoring ", 
                  arg, ".", call. = FALSE)
                paramList[[arg]] <- NULL
            }
        }
    }
    if (!is.null(mergeCells)) {
        if (!is.list(mergeCells)) {
            stop("expected 'mergeCells' to be a list but got ", 
                class(mergeCells))
        }
        for (mergeCell in mergeCells) {
            if (!is.vector(mergeCell)) {
                stop("expected each parameter in 'mergeCells' list to be a vector but got ", 
                  class(mergeCell))
            }
            if (length(mergeCell) != 2) {
                stop("expected each parameter in 'mergeCells' list to be a vector of length  2 but got vector of length ", 
                  length(mergeCells))
            }
        }
        paramList$mergeCells <- mergeCells
    }
    if (!is.null(pagination)) {
        if (!is.numeric(pagination) || length(pagination) > 1) {
            stop("'pagination' must be an integer of length 1 but got ", 
                class(pagination), " of length ", length(pagination))
        }
        paramList$pagination <- pagination
    }
    if (!is.null(style)) {
        if (!is.list(style)) {
            stop("'style' should be a list but got ", class(style))
        }
        paramList$style <- style
    }
    if (!is.null(dateFormat)) {
        paramList$dateFormat <- dateFormat
    }
    paramList$tableHeight <- "500px"
    paramList <- append(paramList, list(...))
    htmlwidgets::createWidget(name = "jexcel", x = paramList, 
        width = if (fullscreen) 
            "100%"
        else 0, height = if (fullscreen) 
            "100%"
        else 0, package = "excelR", 
    )
}
```

Working app after defining above `excelTable2`

```
shinyApp(
    ui =  navbarPage("title", selected = "main", 
        position = "fixed-top", 
        tags$style(type="text/css", "body {padding-top: 70px;}"),
        tabPanel("main", id = "main",
            fluidPage(                
                excelOutput("table", width = "100%", height = "100%")
                #htmlOutput("table", width = "100%", height = "500px")
            )
        )
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
        output$table <-renderExcel(
            excelTable2(
                data = iris,
                autoColTypes = FALSE,
                autoFill = TRUE,
                fullscreen = FALSE,
                lazyLoading = TRUE,
                search = TRUE  
            )
        )
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried using the same attribute you have,  and used it in the standard function and it worked,  I also removed the pagination setting

so this worked for me...

```
server = function(input, output, session) { 
    output$table <-renderExcel(
        excelTable(
            data = iris,
            autoColTypes = FALSE,
            fullscreen = FALSE,
            tableHeight = 500,
            lazyLoading = TRUE,
            search = TRUE  
        )
    )
}
```